# How to remove/disable Spring boot logo on web browser completely?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, favicon

I am trying to remove the spring boot leaf logo on the web browser completely. Attached image for reference:

[image: Sample Icon]

**Attempt 1:**

Added these two in application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false
spring.favicon.enabled=false
```

This only worked in the when hitting pages but if I open localhost:8080/env the Spring logo appears again.

**Attempt 2:** I tried to override the logo with static image. In the index.html.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/Logo.jpg">
```

Same issue only works on static pages but when opening localhost:8080/env the Spring logo appears again.

**Attempt 3:**

```
Project
├── src.main.java.resources
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
```

"favicon.ico" in resources --> static folder. 
Not sure if my browsers are cached but it does not seem to pick up the favicon by default as mentioned in the wiki.

PS, I am using java and spring boot for backend and angular for the UI

Is there a configuration where I can override or completely remove/disable this spring leaf image for every single page?

I Have also followed steps from references below

https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-favicon/

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-favicon

But still hitting /env does not hide the spring boot leaf icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved my issue. Seems like it does not go into the src/main/resources/static/favicon.ico I moved the favicon.ico to src/main/resources and it worked!

```
Project
├── src.main.java
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── static
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
```

This overrides the default spring boot favicon with my own favicon in the resources folder.

Also in the browser I did the following to clear the cache

```
Open up page that has a different logo
Press Ctrl + Shift + J
Right click the refresh button on the browser
Select Empty Cache and hard reload
Reload the page.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want fix this locally, please right click on browser tab and choose "reload".

Answer (score 0):

Add fake controller for all favicon requests

```
@Controller
public class DummyController {

    @GetMapping("favicon.ico")
    @ResponseBody
    public void dummyFavicon() {
        //nop
    }
}
```