# How to avoid Spring Boot Controller catching request for favicon?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, favicon

I have the following Controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping({"/", "/{name}"})
    public String hello(@PathVariable(required = false) String name) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

and this directory structure

```
- resources
    - static
        - favicon.ico
    - templates
        - hello.html
```

When I `GET` `http://localhost:8080/` through the browser, my application prints:

```
Name: null
Name: favicon.ico
```

So the request for `/favicon.ico` goes was caught by my controller, but instead I want that Spring handles this request and returns the `favicon.ico` placed here `resources/static/favicon.ico`

I think there should be a way without adding a handful of lines of configuration.

Comment: Just to make sure - the path to your resources directory containing your favicon.ico is src/main/resources/... , correct?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955039/how-to-remove-disable-spring-boot-logo-on-web-browser-completely

Comment: thank you @AjayKumar solved it by putting <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico"> in to my html head, btw I moved the favicon into src/main/resources/static/images/

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could take is to disable favicon resolution via this [property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

```
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, also this property is deprecated in Spring 5.3.9

Answer (score 0):

I had to include `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">` in my html head, and it worked. The `images` prefix isnt necessary, but I moved the icon into their because I was allowing any unauthenticated request to `/images` so I dont need a extra rule for the `favicon.ico`. Thats my current directory strucutre:

```
- resources
    - static
        - images
            - favicon.ico
    - templates
        - hello.html
```

s/o to [Ajay Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8534285/ajay-kumar) for helping.